# Incrementally adding to cached GraphQL object using Apollo

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I want to pull down a subset of fields of an object from the server, for example:

```
query retrieveUserBasics($id: String!) {
  user(id: $id) {
    name
    age
  }
}
```

And then on a subsequent page I want to download more information about the same user, for example, using a query like:

```
query retrieveUserDetails($id: String!) {
  user(id: $id) {
    birthDate
    favouriteColor
  }
}
```

I was hoping that I could run these two queries at different times and the object would be combined as I ran them, however I see an error occurs in the Apollo reducer (path in the store):

```
apollo.reducerError.error = { type: 'WriteError }
```

I'm assuming this is because Apollo finds an existing object in the store and doesn't know what to do with the new result. The `error` prop in my component is not defined, and the `loading` prop remains `true`.

Is there a way for me to get the result I want, or do I need to rethink how I perform this operation?

Versions:

- react `16.0.0-alpha.12`
- react-apollo `1.4.16`
- redux `3.7.2`

Comment: Does it work if you include the `id` field in both queries?

Comment: @IonutAchim That was exactly it! Thank you so much. If you write this as a proper answer I'll accept it, else I'll self-answer in a day or so if you'd rather not. Thanks again!